# Travel to India with eVISA (internal flight)

Tags: india, e-visas

I am travelling to India, into New Delhi which is a port of entry for an eVisa, then will take an internal flight to Jodhpur, which isn’t on the eVisa list.

Will I have any issues with an eVisa taking an internal flight to Jodhpur?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Will I have any issues with an eVisa taking an internal flight to Jodhpur?

Once you pass immigration control in Delhi, you are free to move inside the country, as those are domestic flights